# Are there any practical benefits to humming?

Tags: transistor

In Transistor, you can, while not in combat, perform flourishes with <kbd>Q</kbd>, and hum with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Is there any reason to use either of these? Given that you can't use them in combat at all, I'm curious to know if they're in the game for anything other than atmosphere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, neither one of these actions actually have a practical purpose. They're there just to add to the flavor and atmosphere of the game.

To note, the humming *does* change when you do it with different tracks in the game, so if you enjoy the music, it's worth it to do when the music changes if you want to hear what it sounds like when Red hums along.

This can be fun to do after you gain access to

> the Sandbox via the Backdoors, which has a jukebox in it. You can then flip through various songs at your leisure to listen to her hum.

Comment: Are you **certain?**  There is one area where you're required to hum near some floating quarter-notes in order to progress.  Slightly before there, there are some floating notes near a bridge.  When I hummed there, the notes disappeared but nothing happened as far as I could tell.  My guess was I'd have find other notes throughout the game to unlock something, but I never found any more.